# What portions of the marketo code snippet can change?

Tags: content-management-system, marketo

My company is using marketo forms, and we are generating the page from a content management system.

We'd like to keep the contribution experience as simple as possible and prevent the user from contributing actual `<script>` tags.

The API documentation says they will give you a block of code that looks like this:

```
<script src="//app-sjqe.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_621"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjqe.marketo.com", "718-GIV-198", 621);</script>
```

My question is, what portions of this code are subject to change?

I am sure the 3 part hypen separated string and the integer being passed in can change.

What about the `app-sjqe.marketo.com` address?

Answer (score 0):

The 3-part string is your Marketo instance ID, and shouldn't really change. The other integer is the form ID, which definitely will change depending on what form you want to embed.

The other thing that you may want to consider, is the other [configurable options](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/) that you can send along with the form embed. For example, in the module that I have made for my CMS, I let the user put an optional 'thank-you' page URL, to redirect the form to after submission, and also a checkbox to optionally open the form in a lightbox on page load.

The simple module I made is for the Sitefinity CMS - happy to share code with you if that helps!